# Nginx Angular2: proxy_pass / transparent internal redirect mobile users

Tags: angular, nginx

I have 2 websites, for desktop we have php based and for mobile we have angular2 based. I want to keep the same domain for both and want to internally redirect mobiles users to Angular2 vhost.

So desktop users land on www.example.com normally and mobiles users internally redirect to m.example.com without browser redirect.

I have tried proxy_pass andI can see see home page but other resources (css.js) etc are throwing 404.

**EDIT:**

Below is our main vhost config:

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE
{

    example.com usd_en;
    en-ae.example.com aed_en;
    ar-ae.example.com aed_ar;
    en-sa.example.com sar_en;
    ar-sa.example.com sar_ar;
    ar.example.com usd_ar;
    #en-qa.example.com qar_en;
    #ar-qa.example.com usd_en;
    en-qa.example.com usd_en;
    ar-qa.example.com usd_en;
    en-kw.example.com kwd_en;
    ar-kw.example.com kwd_ar;
    en-bh.example.com bhd_en;
    ar-bh.example.com bhd_ar;
    en-om.example.com omr_en;
    ar-om.example.com omr_ar;
}

server
{
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}


server
{
    server_name en-qa.example.com ar-qa.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1;
}


server
{
    listen 80 default_server;

    #server_name example.com media.example.com js.example.com css.example.com en-ae.example.com ar-ae.example.com en-sa.example.com ar-sa.example.com test.example.com ar.example.com en-qa.example.com ar-qa.example.com en-kw.example.com ar-kw.example.com en-bh.example.com ar-bh.example.com en-om.example.com ar-om.example.com;

    server_name example.com 54.154.251.109 52.18.89.91 media.example.com js.example.com css.example.com en-ae.example.com ar-ae.example.com en-sa.example.com ar-sa.example.com test.example.com ar.example.com en-kw.example.com ar-kw.example.com en-bh.example.com ar-bh.example.com en-om.example.com ar-om.example.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/public_html;


    location /apple-app-site-association
    {
        default_type application/json;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;


    location ~ onepage
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    location ~ [A-Z]
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase permanent;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "index.php")
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*) $scheme://$host permanent;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/")
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*) $scheme://$host/$1 permanent;
    }

    location /
    {


        #Mobile Redirect
        #include /etc/nginx/vhosts/includes/mobile_redirects.conf;

        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
    }


    location @handler
    {
        ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/
    {
        ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE off;
        #fastcgi_param display_errors off;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include proxy_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $ssl;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=example.com";
    }
}
```

What we are looking if user-agent contain mobile then transparent route it to "m2-app.example.com"

Like: proxy_pass http://m2-app.example.com;

Comment: Post your nginx config that you have used, post the error logs also

Comment: Below is our main vhost config:
https://ufile.io/583pw

What we are looking if user-agent contain mobile then transparent route it to "http://m2-app.example.com"

Like: proxy_pass http://m2-app.example.com;

Comment: Not in comments, please update them in question

Comment: Main question updated

Comment: What are the contents of  `/etc/nginx/vhosts/includes/mobile_redirects.conf;`?

Comment: Its 301 redirecting to m.example.com if user-agent is mobile but you can ignore it as in new config we are replacing it with the new logic whichw e are looking for.

Config updated in main post.

Answer (score 0):

**Using answers as comments since I need formatting**

```
http {

 map $http_user_agent $site_type {
    default "@handler";
    ~(iPhone|Android) "@mobile";
    ~(mobile) "@mobile";
  }
....

    location @mobile {
        proxy_pass http://m2-app.example.com;
    }

    location /
    {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ $site_type; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
    }
```

So above kind of config should help you. Where you determine the handler for try_files based on the user agent.

**Edit-1: New approach**

You can try below config

```
http {

 map $http_user_agent $site_type {
    default "desktop";
    ~(iPhone|Android) "mobile";
    ~(mobile) "mobile";
  }
....

    location /
    {
        root /var/www/html/$site_type;
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri /index.html; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
    }
```

or you can try

```
    location /
    {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri /$site_type/index.html; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
    }
```

Comment: with below config mobile users are still loading desktop site.

https://ufile.io/6ay3c

Comment: That is not complete config, you need to mix it with your config and then use it. that is why i had `....` in the config. Also this file would not have loaded fine, so you probably didn't restart nginx

Comment: I mixed it with my remaining config and then test after the restart. I just omitted the other config and showed you the important one.

So imagine if I don't have the desktop site the basic vhost with above code should atleast route the mobile browser (with matching user-agnet) to mobile site imo.

Comment: Change `default "@handler";` to `default "@mobile";` and see if the mobile site gets loaded? Try to get the mobile site working first and then we fix the user agent mapping

Comment: Sorry for late, developers were changing the technology (desktop and mobile are now on angular).

Lets resume it now.

New architecture: 

We have two sub-folders in the root i.e "mobile" and "desktop" folders. We want to serve content from mobile folder for mobile user-agents and content from desktop for desktop users.

Below is our normal route.
try_files $uri /index.html;

If we manually change it to "try_files $uri /mobile/index.html;" or "try_files $uri /desktop/index.html;" then sites load fine for mobile/desktop respectively but we want it dynamic based on useragent.